# How to checkout a remote git branch ? Or to link a remote branch with a different git directory branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, upstream-branch

I'm working with several repositories

- origin : the remote repository
- back : which is a backup of the repository on my local PC
- uptreams : repository for later pull request

  ```
   git remote -v
   back    /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/repo_backup/webtrees (fetch)
   back    /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/repo_backup/webtrees (push)
   origin  https://github.com/ckl67/webtrees.git (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/ckl67/webtrees.git (push)
   upstream        https://github.com/fisharebest/webtrees.git (fetch)
   upstream        https://github.com/fisharebest/webtrees.git (push)
  ```

Locally
In my "git directory" I'm working with several branches

- master
- work
- dev

In my "git directory" I'm working in branch "work" because I want not to interfere with the "master" branch

My repository "back" is used to test the software.
This "local" repository is used to ftp the (html,php,javascript) code to a local directory for test (Apache,mysql local server)

When I push to repository "back"

```
     git push back
```

All my branches will be pushed too
By default repository "back" will point to branch "master"

So this means that I cannot test my code.
For that I have to go to repository "back",

```
   checkout work
   "test"
   checkout master
```

Because, I have seen that it is not possible to "git push back" when on my repository "back", the branch "work" is activated !!

So I'm a bit in a trouble here.

Question 1)
It is possible to checkout remotely a branch ?

From my "git directory" to checkout branch "work" of my repository "back" ?
So principle would be from my "git directory"

```
 git push back
  --> checkout to "work" in repository "back
 * perform test --> ftp to my local directory in order to test
  --> checkout back to "master" in repository "back
 git push back :: to update all branches (master/work/dev)
```

Solution 2)
It is possible to link git directory/work --> back/master
Meaning, when I "git push back", back/work will be updated
I have tested

```
  git branch --set-upstream-to=back/master work
```

But it didn't work

```
  git branch --set-upstream-to=back/master work
  The 'work' branch is set to follow the remote 'master' branch from 'back'.
  /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/webtrees $ git push back fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
  with the name of your current branch
```

Certainly because, in the "repository back" I have

```
  git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/ckl67/webtrees.git
```

Thank You

Comment: About question 1: **yes**. You can checkout a remote branch.... like, say: `git checkout a-remote/a-branch`. That will get you into _detached HEAD_ state and no local branch will be created.

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposal is not working, can you help please

Answer (score 0):

Running the command on my "git directory", the git result is highlighting that on the repository "back", I'm now pointing to the last commit *(Same as in the local work branch)*

```
git checkout back/work
HEAD is now on 34a8a8e small correction in gitignore file for temporary fix of #3479
```

So, all should be ok !!
However on the repository "back"

```
  VirtualBox:/opt/lampp/htdocs/work/repo_backup/webtrees$ git branch --all
  * master
    work
    remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
    remotes/origin/master
```

I see that branch master is still checked out !!

Can you explain please, and give the trick ?

[image: Issue seen in visual studio code]

Comment: In the last command there, when you do the checkout, there you are on the _remote_ branch.... well, the revision that the remote branch is pointing to... and you are in detached HEAD.... check with `git status`

Comment: _plus_, you should add this as additional info to the question by editing it, not have it as an answer. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Yes you are right, when I run git status in the git directory, I got
        git status
        HEAD détachée sur back/master

So this means ??

Comment: ... So does that mean, that it is not possible to modify the remote branch ?.... Because on repository "back" , I still see that master is checked out

Comment: You can.... but not by _just_ committing locally. You can commit locally working on detached HEAD or with a local branch and then you can push to the remote branch (if working on detached HEAD you can do `git push the-remote HEAD:the-branch`)

Comment: I guess my question was not clear. The question was a possibility to modify a branch from my git directory to a remote branch..

Comment: You can... just not in a single step. Modifying a remote branch is all about _pushing_ to it.